# Selecting text form a swf with a crawler

Tags: flash, web-crawler

Suppose there is a web page with a flash object in it. Is it possible to

1. focus on the object
2. select all text (as if pressing CTRL+A manually)

using a crawler program? Any technology is acceptable.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible / feasible, try to find out how Google does it with their headless Flash Player: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/06/improved-flash-indexing.html

Comment: Indeed, it seems Adobe has released help http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swf_searchability.html, but only for Google and Yahoo!.